# Como puedo hacer que cuando introduzca correctamente el usuario no me aparezca: Usuario o contraseña incorrecta

Tags: c#, sql-server, login

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo solucionar este problema de mi login.

Comment: El código lo tienes que poner como texto. Te puede ayudar leer [ask]. Por otro lado, en la captura de imagen, no veo la apertura de la conexión. Se ve la creación de la conexión y la del comando, pero no el método Open() de la conexión. [Sql Command](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Answer (score 4):

Por el error que te visualizas al utilizar la propiedad [HasRow del SqlDataReader](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows) que esta propiedad indica

> [HasRow](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows): "Obtiene un valor que indica si SqlDataReader contiene una o varias filas."

**Es porque no devuelve filas**

Entonces: Debe ser la consulta

Dale una mirada a la variable "consulta" como la estas armando y como estas concatenando ya que la parte de la contraseña estas colocando directo el control Textbox y deberia ser con la propiedad .Text de dicho control

Es decir esta parte:

**...CONTRASEÑA='" + txtContraseña + "'**

deberia ser:

**...CONTRASEÑA='" + txtContraseña.Text + "'**

Entonces debería quedar así la variable consulta:

```
string consulta = "select * from usuario where USUARIO='" + txtUsuario.Text + "' and CONTRASEÑA='" + txtContraseña.Text + "' ";
```

Pero esto lo deberias ver tu mismo al debuggear tu codigo y ver el valor de la variable.
Si sigue dando error, verifica el comando que concatenas y pruebalo directamente en la DB

Algunas recomendaciones/sugerencias:

- **Concatenación de cadenas en C#**: Aqui te recomendarias que mires el metodo [string.Concat](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?) y tambien [interlopación de cadenas en C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation). Quedaria algo asi:

  string consulta = $"select top 1 1 from usuario where USUARIO='{txtUsuario.Text}' and CONTRASEÑA='{txtContraseña.Text}'";
- **Retorno de la DB en vez de asterisco, devolver solo un 1**: Aqui su no vas a utilizar el resultado del SqlDataReader, primeramente puedes devolver SELECT TOP 1 1 porque solo quieres verificar que exista dicho usuario
- **Si solo devuelves un solo valor de la DB (una fila con una columna) utilizar [ExecuteScalar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar) **: ...y si solo vas a retornar un sola fila y una sola columna lo mejor es utilizar [ExecuteScalar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar) en vez del ExecuteReader. Dale una mirada
- **Prevenir SQL Injection**: En tu ejemplo estas concatenando directamente lo que ingresa al usuario en tu query a la DB, esto como sabras puedas hacer que el usuario pueda ingresar codigo SQL directo ya que no hay filtro. Para eso debes curar esos datos, o mejor utilizar consultas parametrizadas con la DB en el SQlcommando, por ejemplo en tu ejemplo quedaría algo así

  ```
       string consulta = "SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM usuario where USUARIO=@Usuario and CONTRASEÑA=@Contrasenia";

       var comando  = new SqlCommand(consulta, conexion);

       comando.Parameters.Clear();
       comando.Parameters.Add("Usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtUsuario.Text;
       comando.Parameters.Add("Contrasenia", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtContraseña.Text;
  ```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía